# В каких предложениях нарушены синтаксические нормы?

Tags: синтаксис, прямая-речь, деепричастный-оборот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ: в первом и четвёртом предложениях.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синтаксические нормы нарушены в предложениях **1**, **2**, **4**.

**1-е предложение**:

*Бабушка шепнула: «Погоди, внучок, послушай сказку».*

**2-е предложение** тоже должно быть построено с использованием прямой речи:

*Он поинтересовался у меня: «Не могли бы мы завтра встретиться?»*

**4-е предложение** нужно изменить так, чтобы деепричастие ***"говоря"*** и глагол-сказуемое относились к одному действующему лицу:

***Говоря*** об известном поэте, критики **нашли** точные слова.

> [**Деепричастный оборот**](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/deeprichastnyy-oborot-pravilo-i-primery) употребляется только в случаях, когда **обозначает добавочное действие того же лица** (предмета, явления), **что и основной глагол**.

Comment: Что-то есть неправильное в массовом решении подобных домашних заданий одному и тому же студенту. Даже если он понял правила форума и сам тоже тыкает какие-то галочки. Он ведь не утруждает себя объяснениями, почему выбрал тот или иной вариант — надеется, что мы за него проделаем всю эту работу. И эти его сканы тоже... нехорошо как-то.

Comment: @grizzly  Согласен. Я ему уже пытался объснить, что так нельзя. Жалко как-то, ученик ищет помощи, подтверждения своих ответов. Всё, больше не отвечаю.